# Stack Overflow thinks I'm trying to add a version-specific synonym, but that is not quite the case

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

When trying to add [b2](/questions/tagged/b2) as a synonym for [bjam](/questions/tagged/bjam) tag in Stack Overflow, I get:

```
Failed to propose synonym:

Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators
(click on this box to dismiss)
```

But `b2` is the new name for Boost.Build's engine and `bjam` is the old one. The renaming was done in Boost 1.47 release:

> The official name of Boost.Build executable was changed to b2. The
>   bootstrap scripts create a copy with the old name bjam to prevent
>   third-party build scripts from failing.

Quoted from http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_47_0.html, under "Build System"

What can be done to avoid `b2` being considered a version specific synonym by the software? Or, shall I ask moderators to add `b2` as a synonym; if so whom/where do I ask?

Comment: Is it really necessary, to create that tag? Could not [tag:bjam] still be used?

Comment: @kiamlaluno `bjam` name is going to be completely phased out in favor of `b2` some time in the future. New users then might not realize questions on `b2` are under `bjam` tag, and will be surprised if `b2` tag didn't exist already.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't seem compelling.  If there is a B2 reference on the page you linked, I didn't see it. Most websites seem to refer to it as Boost.Build.

If [b2](/questions/tagged/b2) actually gains significant usage, we can always make it (and [bjam](/questions/tagged/bjam)) synonyms of [boost.build](/questions/tagged/boost.build).  Though the boost.build tag is not commonly used (it seems that the [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) tag is favored), it is clear even without looking at the tag wiki what [boost.build](/questions/tagged/boost.build) means.

Comment: As the executable name is `b2` now, newbies will tend to look for `b2` tag when posting questions; not always do they know it is a part of Boost.Build (same goes for `bjam`). It could be like "Hey folks, I got a problem with b2", if they didn't do prior research to find out what `b2` really is. That is my concern.

Comment: BTW there are 116 questions tagged with `bjam` as far as I can tell...

Comment: I am with @usta. It took a while for me to realize that b2 actually meant bjam. And bjam is no longer used but b2 is.

Comment: Yeah, I'm always on the wrong tab when I look at the question count.  It's impossible to Google search 'b2', by the way.  A search for "boost.build" gives far better results, and folks can still use b2, it will just be synonymized to boost.build.  bjam appears to be a [low-level engine component of boost.build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495407/boost-jam-vs-jam).  My vote is still to synonymize all these tags to boost.build.

Comment: I'm all for having all the other tags be synonyms for boost.build. Still can't do that myself due to the aforementioned "Version specific synonym" thing :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not create a [boost-b2](/questions/tagged/boost-b2) to give the casual user an idea of what b2 is.  If they type b2 the tag should still show up.

Comment: I think it will be better to have a b2 tag that is a synonym for boost.build, like @Robert Harvey suggested. Not sure having boost-b2 as well is needed...

Comment: @usta: The problem with b2 is that some other product could just as easily have some feature called b2 and then [tag:b2] becomes yet another ambiguous tag